# How to include "&" in google forms without it being formatted to "&amp;"

Tags: html, special-characters, google-forms

I'm trying to add line breaks to multiple choice questions in Google Forms by using HTML codes and tags.

I've tried `&#10;` and `<br/>`, but Google Forms automatically convert the former to `&amp;#10;` and the latter to `&lt;br/&gt;`.

This is an example with `<br/>`:

[image: screenshot]

Is there any new line character that won't get converted or any way to escape the ampersand to avoid conversion?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ I just spent more than 20 minutes trawling SO and beyond for a solution _ A bit stunned that I can't find one! : |

Comment: If there was, Google might pay you for finding that out. So I guess it is impossible for HTML alone. JavaScript might do, and Python probably.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the answer is quite simple.

**Google Forms do NOT support HTML code**.

It has nothing to do with the ampersand sign